# Communications with Two user Ip

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

any way for Communicate two user in site?
like user1 click in name user2(whith Ip) and send message . i know with database and ajax can save message and send to user2 but its slow and not suitable.
i want Simulation private chatroom and save message history As long as jquery dialog open . 
i found [this](http://nodejs.org/) but i dont know is suitable .
any one have any idea?

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Top code in [site](http://nodejs.org/)

Comment: That code is for Node.js, which is a server-side JavaScript system. Therefore it's essentially a case of "database and ajax".

Comment: Websockets are the way to go, but if not supported on target browsers, then you have no other option than lots of frequent ajax calls to poll a server for inbound messages while posting outbound messages.

Comment: i want Communications without database . can i use fopen,fwrite? how?

Answer (score 1):

Using WebSockets could be a solution? http://www.websocket.org/

This lends it self to a chat system, so you can use Push rather than Pull to check for messages?

Comment: WebSockets not support many browser like firefox . and this is comminucate whit server an client?

Comment: WebSockets is meant to communicate with a server in which multiple clients can connect to and receive notifications when data is available. It's currently not widely available, but when WebSockets is not available, you can use long polling methods instead. Look at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/ or http://dsheiko.com/weblog/websockets-vs-sse-vs-long-polling for more info.

Comment: but all ie version not supported

Comment: As above, if WebSockets is not available, then you have to fallback to normal Ajax calls instead. Another solution is to use Flash based fallbacks. https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js

Answer (score 0):

use [socket.io](http://socket.io) - it provides WebSockets and a couple of fallbacks for shitty IE's

Comment: I kept away from suggesting socket.io because it's a Node.js based solution. It's something you could look at if you have your own dedicated server otherwise you might be out of luck.

Comment: There is node.js tag in the question. So it is a legit answer imho.